# Is $O(n \log(\log n))$ worse or better than $O(n^2)$?

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

I'm working on implementing the Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++. In doing so, I already have a function that will find all the prime numbers up to a given $N$; it does so in $O(n^2)$.

From reading some work on the Sieve of Eratosthenes, it runs in $O(n\log(\log n))$. Now given that $O(\log(\log n))$ is faster than $O(n)$ which is faster than $O(n^2)$, I would wager that:
$$
O(\log(\log n)) < O(n) < O(n) * O(\log(\log n)) < O(n^2)
$$

Is this the case, or is it:
$$
O(\log(\log n)) < O(n) * O(\log(\log n)) < O(n) < O(n^2)
$$

Comment: The first inequality chain is correct, since $O(log(log(n)))$ is worse than $O(1)$, the second chain is not correct, but to answer the main question : $O(nlog(log(n)))$ is better than $O(n^2)$

Comment: Define "worse or better"

Comment: How did you conclude that$$\mathcal O(n)\mathcal O(\log(\log(n)))<\mathcal O(n)$$Surely as $n\to\infty$, you see that $\mathcal O(\log(\log(n)))\gg\mathcal O(1)$?

Comment: An [image](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+n*log(log(n))+and+n%5E2+from+n%3D1+to+50) is worth a thousand words

Comment: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/  ??

Comment: Since you already know $O(\log\log n)<O(n)$ you can multiply by $n$ on both sides to get $O(n\log\log n)<O(n^2)$.

Comment: Even if @SimplyBeautifulArt writes $\mathcal O(\log(\log(n)))\gg\mathcal O(1)$ as $n \to \infty$, $\mathcal O(\log(\log(n)))$ is almost constant. There are approximately $10^{80}$ atoms in the universe. The natural logarithm of this is approximately $184$, and the natural logarithm of $184$ is approximately $5.2$.

Comment: @md2perpe Sure, but $\log(\log(e^{e^{10000000}}))=10000000$.  It does not grow fast, and yes, it certainly looks constant and bounded for small enough $n$, but $\mathcal O$ doesn't ask about small $n$.  It asks for the behavior as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: On the other hand, your comment was probably more geared towards saying that $\mathcal O(n\log(\log(n)))\ll\mathcal O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: Perhaps I should have written "practically constant" rather than "almost constant". How big will $\log(\log n)$ be in the posters' program?

Comment: If you take $n=10^{12}$ 1 trillion then $n^2=10^{24}$ but $n\log\log(n)\approx 3\cdot 10^{12}$ assuming natural logarithm. So it's pretty much better

Comment: @Peter So in the case of my program, if my overall function had two loops within, one that ran $O(nlog(logn)$ and the other $O(n)$, the overall function is $O(nlog(logn)$ since that dominates $O(n)$ correct?

Comment: @datta In the case of nested loops, we must multiply the complexities and get $O(n^2log(log(n)))$. Are the loops seperated ? In this case, you are riight.

Comment: @Peter There are 3 loops. Loop 1 runs at $O(n)$; inside of that is the heart of the Sieve of Eratosthenes (Loop 2) which runs at $O(log(logn))$. So the worst case for Loop 1 with Loop 2 nested within is $O(nlog(logn))$. The final loop, Loop 3, is separated and runs at $O(n)$. So the overall complexity of my program is $O(nlog(logn)) + O(n) = O(nlog(logn)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$O(n \log(\log n)) < O(n\log n) < O(n^2)$

The second chain of inequalities in your answer is incorrect, because $O(n) * O(\log(\log n)) > O(n),$ since $O(\log(\log n)) > O(1)$